# Using the memory alloted to some other process

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have an application and I want to test if the out of memory exception is handled properly .So should I fill the memory somehow to force that condition to come up. How do i do it?

Comment: `std::vector<int> x; for(int i=0;;i++)x.push_back(i);` would be an obvious starting point.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: `malloc(1000000000000000000)` would be a lot faster...

Comment: @Constantinius: It'll be faster, but on some notable systems (especially Linux) huge allocations will seem to succeed, but you'll get a failure (exception) if/when you try to *use* the memory.

Comment: Probably best to fake it. Then you can check the best case scenario whereby that particular execution path is followed to completion.

Comment: Also on Linux it's possible to limit process's virtual memory using `setrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, ...)`

Comment: i want to fill the memory of one particular process so that wen it tries to allocate memory " out of memory exception is generated"

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can simulate low resources conditions using Application Verifier.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/aa480483.aspx).